# JQuery - Click Link Auto fill in input field

Tags: jquery

I got a bit of a pickle.

What im trying to do is click on a link and it automatically puts a value into an input field.

I have an quicksearch table that auto sorts when you type something in the search box. I want to be able to click a link with a specific name that automatically puts that value in the search field.

So far i have this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#test').click(function() {
    $('.qs_input').val( $(this).text() ).keyup();
    return false;

    });
```

});

Cheers,

Comment: And what would the mark-up be like, for those links?

Comment: What event triggers the search? Some key-event?

Comment: @david

The links are actually hot spots on images and listed in a Dynamic (Searchable) table. 

I need to click a link that automatically populates the search field for the table. Im doing this because i want users to be able to click regions from a map, the image then changes to that region the user clicked on, which then updates the table. The table functionality is already working. I just need to be able to click a link on the image or in the table, for that to then auto put text in a search field called .search_field.

Comment: Im using this same table http://beckelman.net/Demos/jQueryTableSorterAndQuickSearch/ and i want to be able to click a link that puts text in that text area so it automatically defines the search.

Comment: Im not sure if its on keyup or not, it seems to be though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('#yourLink').click(function() {
    $('#yourInput').val( $(this).text() ).keyup();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't even bother with the `return false;` imo.

Comment: @Endophage If it's an ANCHOR, then it should be disabled, so that the browser doesn't update the URL of the page (based on the link's href attribute).

Comment: I thought jQuery disabled the link when it bound the click event to it...? haven't had to do it in a while.

Comment: @Endophage Nope. The default action of the anchor will occur unless it is prevented from within the click handler (by either returning false, or calling the preventDefault method on the event object).

Comment: @sime Thank you so much! So you were right baout it not working because its on an upkey event. But when you say trigger the event manually what do you mean exactly

Comment: @Jake I've simplyfied my answer. As you can see, there is a `keyup()` call in the code. This call triggers the keyup event on the text-box.

Comment: @sime sorry i noticed that and put it in, it still didnt work for me though  unfortunately.

Comment: @Jake Did you replace my placeholder selectors with your own ones?

Comment: yeah here is the code so far

$(document).ready(function() {

 $('#test').click(function() {
  $('.qs_input').val( $(this).text() ).keyup();
  return false;

  });
});

Comment: i put it in my original question for you to see

Comment: @sime the actualy code works as in it put the text in the field. But the keyup(); function isnt making a difference.

Comment: @Jake Then (instead of `keyup()`) try one of these: `keydown()`, `keypress()` and `change()`.

Comment: Awesome! thanks man it turned out to be keydown() thanks heaps man!

Comment: How would you create a button that Clears the search bar? as well ?Sorry forgot to add this in there

Comment: Dont woprry i figured it out. Cheers !