# Autofill a HTML form with database entries

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, autofill

I want to autofill two input elements bi clicking on a link. Here is the code I'm using:

```
 <script>

    function autoFill(depart_from, depart_to) {
        document.getElementById('depart_from').value = depart_from;
        document.getElementById('depart_to').value = depart_to;
    }

 </script>
```

And here is the link:

...

```
echo "<tr class='odd'>";
echo "<td><span class='hover'><ahref='#'onClick='autoFill(" . $row['departure'] . ", " . $row['destination'] . "return false;'>" . $row['departure'] ." » ". $row['destination'] . "</a><span></td>";
echo "</tr>";
```

Can't get it to work! What am I doing wrong?

Thanx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by looking at this question: [JQuery - Click Link Auto fill in input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099764/jquery-click-link-auto-fill-in-input-field)

Answer (score 0):

For starters, the spacing is broken in your anchor tag:

```
<ahref='#'onClick='autoFill(
```

should be:

```
<a href='#' onClick='autoFill(
```

Additionally, you never close the function and separate statements with a semi-colon:

```
autoFill(" . $row['departure'] . ", " . $row['destination'] . "return false;
```

should be:

```
autoFill(" . $row['departure'] . ", " . $row['destination'] . ");return false;
```

Finally, you may want to wrap those method parameters in quotes:

```
autoFill(" . $row['departure'] . ", " . $row['destination'] . ");return false;
```

should be:

```
autoFill('" . $row['departure'] . "', '" . $row['destination'] . "');return false;
```

There may be more.  One thing to keep in mind is to try to not use `echo` statements to emit large blocks of HTML.  It makes the code a little less easy to read, and more importantly it adds another layer of "stringification" which makes including quotes in strings slightly more difficult.

Comment: The correct way to pass a PHP variable into javascript would be to use `json_encode`. Not `addslashes`, not `htmlentities` (or `htmlspecialchars`) and most certainly not nothing.

Comment: @Frit van Campen: Indeed, there is a good bit more work to be done with the OP's code.

Comment: Thanx! I will try a different approach on this. There has to be a cleaner way of doing it!

Comment: Solved it! With a different approach and not in a stupid way this time

Comment: @Ismailp: Glad to hear it!  It may be worth updating your question with the new code, or posting it as an answer, to add to the content of this thread.  Other users may find this useful someday.

Comment: @David: Can't answer my own questions yet. but I solved it by reading this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099764/jquery-click-link-auto-fill-in-input-field

Answer (score 0):

The spacing on your `a` tag is wrong, you need a space between the `a href`.

You never close the brackets for the function call, and I think you may need to put the parameters in quote marks, depending on their type:

`autoFill('" . $row['departure'] . "', '" . $row['destination'] . "'); return false;'`